# How to access and use the useLottie returns

Tags: reactjs, lottie

I am just trying to understand how the lottie-react return parameters can be accessed from a component. In the example component that they have setup, there is a list of returns https://gamote.github.io/lottie-react/hooks/useLottie#returns.

For example, how can I access `Lottie.setDirection()` to set it to `-1` on click so the animation plays backwards? Or `Lottie.pause()` to pause the animation?

```js
    import { useLottie } from "lottie-react";
    import groovyWalkAnimation from "./groovyWalk.json";

    const style = {
      height: 300,
    };

    const Example = () => {
      const options = {
        animationData: groovyWalkAnimation,
        loop: true,
        autoplay: true,
      };
      const { View } = useLottie(options, style);
      return View;
    };

    export default Example;
```

Answer (score 1):

The methods you're looking for are returned next to the `View` property by the `useLottie` hook. Example with `play()` and `pause()` methods:

```js
import { FC } from "react";
import { useLottie } from "lottie-react";
import groovyWalkAnimation from "./groovyWalk.json";

export const MyApp: FC = () => {
  // 1) destructuring required methods from `useLottie`s response
  const {  View, play, pause } = useLottie({
    animationData: groovyWalkAnimation,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true
  });

  // 2) Usege of the methods
  return (
    <>
      <h1>My awesome animation</h1>

      {View}

      <button onClick={() => play()}>Play</button>
      <button onClick={() => pause()}>Pause</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi @DavidG, I am eagerly waiting to use your lottie-react package in React@18.0.1  ....

Help me update your package in npm ... :)

Comment: Hi @ZiauddinZiya07, you can use the latest version (`lottie-react@2.3.1`) which has support for React v18.